# 'only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars' error

Tags: python, numpy, bisect

I have such Python code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy import optimize as opt

def func1(x):
    f1 = math.exp(x-2)+x**3-x
    return f1

solv1_bisect = opt.bisect(func1, -1.5, 1.5)

x1 = np.linspace(-1.5,1.5) 
y1 = func1(x1)
plt.plot(x1,y1,'r-')
plt.grid()

print('solv1_bisect = ', solv1_bisect)
```

and I've got the error message such as

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Please help me to fix it, Thanks!

Comment: Next time try to introduce better what you are trying to do, it may be helpful to others.

Comment: When you get errors like this, pay attention to where they occur.  Show us the `traceback`, the full error message.  In this case it pointed to a `math.exp` line.  Did you take time to look up that function?  Checking the documentation before posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using [`math.exp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.exp) that expects a Python scalar, for example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import math
>>> math.exp(np.arange(3))  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-10-3ac3b9478cd5>", line 1, in <module>
    math.exp(np.arange(3))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Use [`np.exp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html) instead:

```
def func1(x):
    f1 = np.exp(x - 2) + x ** 3 - x
    return f1
```

The difference between `np.exp` and `math.exp` is that `math.exp` works with Python's numbers (floats and integers) while `np.exp` can work with numpy arrays. In your code the argument `x` is a numpy array, hence the error.

Comment: OMG it works!!! Thanks a lots! But what different between math.exp and np.exp?

Comment: @YYen added an explanation